# How do I use transform to scale division with just css

Tags: css

**Problem statement:**

I am using the following to scale a `<div>` with window re-size using just CSS:

```
position:       relative;
width:          40%;
height:         0em;
padding-bottom: 30%;
```

and it works as far as the width and height are concerned.

The division contains a static `<img>` and it scales okay as well.

However, the content also includes a moving image (.png) using `new Image()` to create it and further JS code to move it. And this .png is **not** scaling with the size of the `<div>`. As a matter of fact, this .png does not even show.

If I use Safari to zoom in and out, everything scales - the `<div>` size and the static image. The .png also shows as it should.

**Question**:

So ... how can I emulate the scaling using transform and similar calls that substitute for the above position-width-height-paddingbottom group?

***[EDITED] on Sept 27, 2015***

FWIW, I'm very new to jsFiddle and simply added a jsFiddle. Hope this ends all discussion (except for the solution to the problem illustrated in this jsFiddle, of course) ... http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2/

***[EDITED] on Sept 5, 2015***

I don't know if this will backfire ... but:

(a) *Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior*:

I already stated "scale a `<div>` with window re-size using just CSS"

(b) *a specific problem or error*:

I already stated that a .png is **not** scaling with the size of the `<div>`.

(c) *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it*

I deliberately passed on this because I chose rather to seek how to use transform instead of the above grayed-out block. Besides, I know transform works, .png included.  What I do not know is how to adjust the `transform: scale[xxx]` according to the changing window width.

The "beast" I'm trying to scale with window width is that "camera shutter" jQuery plug-in.  BTW, the above ".png" is the black camera shutter itself.

(d) other responses below swerve into the land of SVG and I simply do not understand any of it, none, zip.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -2):

The first step is to admit you have a problem -- in this case the problem is your addiction to CSS (to do anything geometrically comprehensive in a systematic way) .  It's okay, it's an industry wide catastrophic legacy would which has yet to even begin the process of [blah blah]
Try the SVG-everything approach, it worked for me.
https://github.com/Terebinth/Vickers

Notice the use of `transform_matrix` on line 63
https://github.com/Terebinth/Vickers/blob/master/lib/vickers__workshop.coffee#L63

(Vickers as a whole is in dire need of refactor -- deficiencies in data flow / data-structure setup and performance issues related to insufficient use of the Immutables library for the `shouldComponentUpdate` thing, as well as just style and consistency -- but it was for prototyping only and I've moved on.  I hope it inspires people to move out of the HTML/CSS ghetto)

Comment: :)  Fine , fine.  Learn to do smooth transformations with just CSS.

Comment: Your solution to scaling a div is to refactor his entire page to use SVG instead?

Comment: I don't mean to be cruel, I just thought I might help another pilgrim up out of the dungeon into the pure light of homogeneous coordinates.  CSS is a horrible nightmare; many people think there is no alternative.  Stockholm syndrome.  CSS should be used to style (Hyper)Text(Markup) only-- not as a global graphics solution for any kind of app.

Comment: Do you have a link to an article that makes a case for svg over css for layout? Also, are there any companies that are doing it? As someone who's pretty comfortable with css, I would be curious to see a reasoned argument for using svg for layout instead.

Comment: I'm working on one, but it's not a priority.  There are other (better than me) advocates of an SVG centred approach out there, but I haven't done a comprehensive search.  It's kind of grist for a heated argument I guess.  Certainly, there is a lot of inertia built up in the development industry over optimising HTML/CSS capabilities.  In my opinion there are much better and more appropriate tools available now.  Really I should attempt to make the case in long form and link it here.  Then you could decide reasonably.  On the other hand I might use the time coding instead of blogging.

Comment: The one potentially useful thing about my answer was the link to the proof-of-concept I did, implementing a React app using only SVGs and matrix math for placement tranforms.  It's a much better way to do responsive apps, even though the MineSweeper implementation there only responds to screen resizing, there are lots of possibilities for other graphics 'resposes' to changing view states.

Comment: I truly apologize to everyone ... very new to jsFiddle and simply added a jsFiddle without considering that it be public. Hope this ends it ... this uses -xxx-transform: scale(x,y) very nicely. BUT, this jsFiddle illustrates a severe scaling problem I desperately need help with = http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2/